# Location-based actions on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, geofencing

I am building a private location-based social network, so it would be great if people could be checked in automatically when they arrive. Is there anyway of doing this on iOS? What about Android?

On iPhones, there is an option to have a reminder about something when you arrive in a particular location so I guess the iPhone is capable, but I don't know whether it's a public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ios you could use `startMonitoringForRegion:` in `CLLocationManager`, which should detect boundary crossing of a specified region, and even relaunch your app if it isn't running at the time

Comment: Well that answers the iOS question. Now I need to find an Android equivalent.

Comment: Using your iOS function name, I found out that it's called 'geofencing' and the function is addProximityAlert in LocationManager. Thanks!